# Does an open source markup->HTML tool exist for Confluence wiki markup?

Tags: markup, confluence

There are many libraries for transforming markups like reStructuredText and markdown to HTML.  I have some users who are familiar with the markup used in Atlassian's Confluence wiki product, which is unfortunately proprietary -- is there any open source compiler for the confluence wiki markup format, or possibly something that would transform it to an intermediate format?

Answer (score 1):

I think Confluence uses the [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29) markup format. I have used over the last few years a rails application that used the gem [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/) to do the transformation, and I could switch between the 2 formats. I never checked if it is complete interchangeable, however.

You could check for yourself if it is sufficient at [Try RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/try-redcloth/).